# Compact way to call a class member to all elements of a list of objects

Tags: python

Question: How to define a compact construction for this loop:

```
for V in L:
   V.f()
```

Where:

- `L`: is a list of objects of a given type `A`
- `f()`: a method of `A`.

For example:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        print "foobar... "

# Construct the list
a1 = A()
a2 = A()
a3 = A()
L = [a1, a2, a3]

for V in L:
    V.f()
```

I found a way of doing that with a map call and a lambda function:

```
 map(lambda x: x.f(), L)
```

However, this call returns a list, which I wish not to construct.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: `for V in L:
    V.f( )` seems an easy and very readable way to do it

Comment: What is wrong with the for loop you already have?

Comment: `[ V.f() for V in L ]` is more compat, but also return a result list .and may I know why you don't want return a list ? if you don't want , just ignore it .

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is to use a loop as you mentioned. Any other solution will be semantically incorrect.

(What you are saying is "For each item in L, do f." That is, you are being imperative. A for loop says exactly that.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a list as a return value, then your for loop is the best way.

```
for V in L:
    V.f()
```

Alternatively, you could use one of python's best features, list comprehensions, and simply not assign it to any variable. List comprehensions are usually faster.

```
[ V.f() for V in L]
```